# USB connection between Odroid and PC

Tags: android, odroid

How can I send bytes between Odroid with android and my pc? I want to use usb but I am looking for someone who do that and can help me. I don't know how can I start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Developer option from android setting and restart your adb. Odroid is able to connect with usb like normal device.